# Git не хочет делать push?

Tags: svn, bitbucket, git

```
REAL@BENTLY /c/LS/sites/home/test.loc/www/gallery (master)
$ git push -u origin master
Password for 'https://nickname@bitbucket.org':
error: src refspec master does not match any.
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://nickname@bitbucket.org/nickname/jquery-g
allery.git'

REAL@BENTLY /c/LS/sites/home/test.loc/www/gallery (master)
$ git pull origin master
Password for 'https://nickname@bitbucket.org':
fatal: Couldn't find remote ref master
Unexpected end of command stream
```

Что не так, подскажите?

**[ `git status` ]**

```
REAL@BENTLY /c/LS/sites/home/test.loc/www/gallery (master)
$ git status
# On branch master
#
# Initial commit
#
# Untracked files:
#   (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
#
#       .hg/
#       .hgignore
#       README.md
#       css/
#       index.html
#       js/
nothing added to commit but untracked files present (use "git add" to track)
```

**[ `git add .` ]**

```
REAL@BENTLY /c/LS/sites/home/test.loc/www/gallery (master)
$ git add .
fatal: LF would be replaced by CRLF in .hg/cache/branchheads
```

**[ `git remote rm origin` ]**

```
REAL@BENTLY /c/ls/sites/home/test.loc/www/jquery-gallery (master)
$ git remote rm origin

REAL@BENTLY /c/ls/sites/home/test.loc/www/jquery-gallery (master)
$ git remote add origin git@bitbucket.org:nickname/jquery-gallery.git

REAL@BENTLY /c/ls/sites/home/test.loc/www/jquery-gallery (master)
$ git push -u origin master
The authenticity of host 'bitbucket.org (206.223.241.182)' can't be established.

RSA key fingerprint is 97:8c:1b:f2:6f:14:6b:5c:3b:ec:aa:46:46:74:7c:40.
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)? yes
Warning: Permanently added 'bitbucket.org,206.223.241.182' (RSA) to the list of
known hosts.
Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

p.s. ip изменен.

**[ `обновился` ]**

Перенес в другой каталог исходники:

```
REAL@BENTLY /c/localgit/jquery-gallery (master)
$ git push -u origin master
Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

**[ `Решение` ]**

Наверное больше для себя чем для кого-то оставлю заметку.

В общем дело было в `public key`, ввел другой `public key`, который находится в файле

`C:\Documents and Settings\REAL\.ssh\id_rsa.pub`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Вероятно в вашем локальном репозитории не создан refspec для бранча master, т.к. репозиторий пустой. Выполните git status. В результате вы должны получить ответ, наподобие этого:

```
# On branch master
nothing to commit (working directory clean)
```

Если ответ не содержит строки "On branch master", то нужно выполнить первый коммит. После этого push должен отработать.

Comment: Есть у меня там что коммитить, статус см. что статус показал показал.

Comment: Нечего у вас комитить. Ничего не добавлено в staging area. 

Зачем кстати, вам комитить в репозиотрий файлы меркуриала из директории .hg?

Добавьте в staging area только исходники, исключив .hg и .hgignore. 

Ну и проблема у вас с символами перевода строк. Нужно настроить. 

См. git config  и свойство core.autocrlf

Comment: Че мне с этим `public key` делать? Я его сгенерировал с помощью `PuTTygen`, затем добавил в `SSH KEYS` с меткой в аккаунте на `ButBucket`, не пойму что еще нужно...

Comment: Все расписано по шагам в инструкции
https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/BITBUCKET/Set+up+SSH+for+Git

Comment: Спасибо, уже решил, но гляну.

Answer (score 3):

У меня тоже такая фигня случалась когда пытался использовать путь по https. Возможно такая фигня случается если репозиторий приватный и git не использует твои ssh ключи.

Удали старый `origin` и добавь новый с другой урлой:

```
git remote rm origin
git remote add origin git@bitbucket.org:nickname/jquery-gallery.git
```

Должно заработать.

Comment: Я так понимаю что у меня может быть какие-то проблемы с `public key`?

Comment: да нет, если вы всё сделали по инструкции (через `ssh-keygen`)

Answer (score 0):

у меня была такая же ошибка.
Решилась, когда добавила команду "git branch -M main" перед пушем